# libgpiod read value Operation not permitted

Tags: gpio, python, c++, libgpiod

Trying to read the values from gpio chips in a Python script using the gpiod python module. When calling get_value() we are getting "Operation not permitted".

Have tried running the python script as both `root` and `pi` user.

My python test script

```
import logging
import gpiod

_log = logging.getLogger(__name__)

device = "/dev/gpiochip3"
chip = None

try:
    chip = gpiod.chip(device, gpiod.chip.OPEN_BY_PATH)
except OSError:
    _log.warning("Unable to open gpio chip {device}.")

if chip is None:
    _log.error("GPIO chip {device} not available")

line = chip.get_line(12)
if line is not None:
    print("Line name: ", line.name)
    print(" Line direction: ", line.direction)
    print(" Line consumer: ", line.consumer)
    print(" Line active state: ", line.active_state)
    print(" Line bias: ", line.bias)
    print(" Line value: ", line.get_value())
else:
    print("Line {line_name} was not found")
```

Running this I get the following output

```
root@rpi2:~# python3.9 gpio.py 
Line name:  
 Line direction:  1
 Line consumer:  
 Line active state:  2
 Line bias:  1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/gpio.py", line 25, in <module>
    print(" Line value: ", line.get_value())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/gpiod/libgpiodcxx/__init__.py", line 611, in get_value
    raise OSError(
PermissionError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: 'error reading GPIO line value'
```

We have tried using the gpoizero, which seem to work better.
The problem with gpiozero is

1. Support for GPIO expander access the chip directly via I2C-bus, and not via the OS.
2. It does not support the GPIO expander we are using.

Running Debian Bullseye on a Raspberry Pi.

```
root@rpi2:~# uname -a
Linux rpi2 5.15.44-rt46-v8+ #1 SMP PREEMPT Mon Jun 13 10:36:58 CEST 2022 aarch64 GNU/Linux
```

I also tried creating a C++ application using the C++ bindings of the libgpiod. I am getting the same error there, Operation not permitted.

```
#include <chrono>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <gpiod.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    std::string CHIP = "gpiochip1;
    int         LINE_OFFSET = 2;

    gpiod::chip chip(CHIP);
    gpiod::line line = chip.get_line(LINE_OFFSET);

    std::cout << "Line name: " << line.name();
    std::cout << " Line direction: " << line.direction();
    std::cout << " Line consumer: " << line.consumer();
    std::cout << " Line active state: " << line.active_state();
    std::cout << " Line bias: " << line.bias();
    std::cout << " Line value: " << line.get_value();
}
```

Using the command line tools `gpioget` works fine. This tool is using the C-library of libgpiod. Could then the problem be the C++ and Python bindings?

```
root@rpi2:~# gpioget gpiochip3 12
1
```

```
root@rpi2:~# gpiodetect 
gpiochip0 [pinctrl-bcm2711] (58 lines)
gpiochip1 [raspberrypi-exp-gpio] (8 lines)
gpiochip2 [ftdi-cbus] (4 lines)
gpiochip3 [1-0021] (16 lines)
gpiochip4 [1-0020] (16 lines)
```

The gpiochip3 and gpiochip 4 are both PCAL6416APW on the I2C-bus. They are configured in /boot/config as following

```
dtoverlay=pca953x,pcal6416,addr=0x20,irq_gpios=17,reset=16
dtoverlay=pca953x,pcal6416,addr=0x21,irq_gpios=2,reset=12
```

```
root@rpi2:~# ls -l /dev/gpiochip*
crw-rw---- 1 root gpio 254, 0 Sep 16 13:34 /dev/gpiochip0
crw-rw---- 1 root gpio 254, 1 Sep 16 13:34 /dev/gpiochip1
crw-rw---- 1 root gpio 254, 2 Sep 16 13:35 /dev/gpiochip2
crw-rw---- 1 root gpio 254, 3 Sep 16 13:35 /dev/gpiochip3
crw-rw---- 1 root gpio 254, 4 Sep 16 13:35 /dev/gpiochip4
```

Comment: I wrote using Raspberry Pi, on Debian Bullseye.
Using gpioget works fine, on these devices, so why would you say they are imaginary?

Comment: I added the output from gpiodetect which lists 5 devices.

Comment: The gpiochip3 is something we have made.

Comment: I added some information on the gpiochip3 and gpiochip4.

Comment: Permissions?  Edit result of `ls -l /dev/gpiochip*` into your question.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to set the line request.

C++

```
gpiod::line_request config;
config.consumer     = "Line";
config.request_type = gpiod::line_request::DIRECTION_INPUT;
line.request(config);
```

Same for Python:

```
config = gpiod.line_request()
config.consumer     = "Line"
config.request_type = gpiod.line_request.DIRECTION_INPUT
line.request(config)
```